# Can I create Dynamic Meta Images using a custom URL and an image?

Tags: javascript, php, metadata, meta-tags, open-graph-beta

I came across a tool that can dynamically change the image if you change the name at the end of the picture URL.

e.g., `https://img1.niftyimages.com/3kw/eoto/qwjd?name=john%20smith`

What I would like to do, is send john smith something like

```
https://website.com?utm_campaign=mike
```

And Mikes name load up in the meta image.

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://img1.niftyimages.com/3kw/eoto/qwjd?name=mike" />
```

I've currently tested this in PHP and Javascript.

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$url = "https://img1.niftyimages.com/3kw/eoto/qwjd?name=";
$utm = "utm_campaign";
echo "$url$utm";

?>

<meta name="twitter:image" content="$url$utm" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var url_string = "https://www.first-website.com?utm_campaign=mike"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var A = url.searchParams.get("utm_campaign");
var B = "https://img1.niftyimages.com/3kw/eoto/qwjd?name=";
var image = B+A;

document.write('<meta name="twitter:image" content="' + image + '" />');
    }
})();

</script>
```

FYI, I'm a complete n00b